# Alerts not working - Timer Lock

Tags: alert, timer-jobs

I've checked content database;

```
SELECT * FROM timerlock WITH (nolock)
```

Then having checked the eventcache table;

```
SELECT * FROM eventcache WITH (nolock) WHERE EventData is not null
```

I've got a longlist of alerts that have not sent.

I tried accessing the server in question and following this process:

1. Stop the Windows SharePoint Services Timer service
2. Navigate to "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\SharePoint\Config\ and delete all the .xml files - DO NOT DELETE THE cache.ini FILE!
3. Open the cache.ini file in notepad and change the number value to 1 then save the file.
4. Start the Windows SharePoint Services Timer service.

Unfortunately that hasn't worked.

Comment: Can anyone assist?

Comment: Have you customized the alerts and/or the alert template? Do you have SP Health Analyzer warnings? What is your server configuration? Other than restarting the timer service what else have you tried? http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13771.troubleshooting-steps-for-sharepoint-alert-email-does-not-go-out.aspx